# Align android button to the screen center

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout

I was wondering if there is a chance to align the play button as [from screenshot](https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/i-bZQJB4d2cywTaCwKW-lPm7LDmAxtRA5RKaIVIQbwGkzHTCqRpdUbvSIhnSU4rT0ao=w1848-h981-rw) at the center of the screen. Unfortunately, I have only succeeded in doing such with the white space that I wish to remove. The whole code sample has been attached to the question upon request. This now illustrates the area, where two blocks must be separated with a constraint layout with a required button in the center

[image]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ROOT"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#f5907c"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dummyViewTop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/top_clock"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:text="@string/DEFAULT_CLOCK_VALUE"
            android:textSize="90sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/CONTROL_BUTTON_RESET"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_reset_24"
            android:contentDescription="@string/reset_button_desc"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#2e3a52"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dummyViewBottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_clock"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/DEFAULT_CLOCK_VALUE"
            android:textSize="90sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: upd: supplied the personal sample image

Comment: use constraint layout and set button to horizontally and vertically center

Comment: @Anshul could you provide me with the code snippet, or whatever value would go for the constraint height?

Comment: if you add code, it will be helpful to assist you correctly

Comment: @ShobhithYadav upd: supplied the code sample

Comment: have you worked on constraint layout before?

Comment: Unfortunately, the white space problem persists event with the constraint layout =c See screenshot 2

Comment: @ShobhithYadav Not really

Comment: Can you share your entire xml code

Comment: You need to "flatten" this XML... have one `ConstraintLayout` as the root and all other views contained in it - with no nested `LinearLayout` / `RelativeLayout` stuff. But that's not the cause of your "whitespace"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will solve this in this manner by making constraint layout as the root layout. It will flatten our view hierarchy and reduces the code complexity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/ROOT"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    
    <TextView
        android:background="#f5907c"
        android:id="@+id/top_clock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:text="10:00"
        android:textSize="90sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_clock"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_clock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="10:00"
        android:background="#2e3a52"
        android:textSize="90sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_clock"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/btn_setting"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/add_btn"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bottom_clock"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_clock"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btn_refresh"/>
    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/btn_refresh"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/add_btn"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bottom_clock"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_clock"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn_setting"/>
    

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

I suggest you to explore Constraint layout some time

Comment: wow! This is exactly the thing, thanks a lot!!

Comment: is there a chance I can make them appear closer to each other?

Comment: yes....for the first image view add horizontal chain style to packed and and you can adjust the spacing using margin later on

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/CONTROL_BUTTON_RESET"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_reset_24"
            android:scaleType="center"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this should make your button center in the middle of the screen, provided your ConstratintLayout occupies the whole screen.

Also, don't use `ImageButton`, use an `ImageView` and apply a click listener to it.

Comment: didn't really help. the whitespace is still there =c

Comment: post the image of the drawable please.

Comment: please find the picture 3 attached

Comment: your picture 3 isn't the picture of the drawable alone. i edited the answer, please try to follow it, especially regarding the width/height and drawable being set as part of `background` now

Comment: still the same, I now also get Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.winnie.chessclock/my.winnie.chessclock.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)

Comment: the error is clear, ImageView cannot be cast to ImageButton - why are you insisting on the `ImageButton` ? Your pictures (the ones you want to end up with) look nothing like `ImageButton`s. An ImageButton is a rectangular button, that has an image instead of text. Your pictures look like you need a CircularImageView or any variant of a round image view. Please adapt your activity code to use ImageView instead of ImageButton. @Aleksandrs

Answer (score 0):

you have to give a constraint properly to your button like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="mate_parent">

     <TextView
         android:id = "@+id/textView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```